# Regex to rearrange filename strings?

Tags: regex, rename

I need to rename approximately 50,000 files and can't find regex examples that work. Here is the pattern for all the filenames

```
myfiletitle.jpg_download=12500
```

The numeric IDs at the end of the filenames are all the same length -- 5 digits -- and all the filenames follow this pattern. From a Bash shell, I want to run a batch rename to restructure the filenames as follows:

12500_myfiletitle.jpg

This should be easy but I just can't get the regex to work. I've had some success with the following, but overall I can't get the full solution:

```
s/\(.*\).../\1/
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which tool are you planning to use?  `sed` or `perl` or ...?

Comment: Use a software name BULK RENAME UTILITY......... Best software ever to rename batch file... Even for thousands of file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s/\(.*)\.jpg_download=\([0-9]\{5\}\)$/\2_\1.jpg/
```

This is using `sed`-like regular expressions, as hinted at in the question's illustrative regex.  In Perl, you'd write:

```
s/(.*)\.jpg_download=(\d{5})$/$2_$1.jpg/
```

Comment: Thank you! Here is the final string I went with: `ls | sed 's/\(.*\)\.JPG_download=\([0-9]\{6\}\)$/mv -- & \2_\1.jpg/' | sh` in which all of the files in the directory were JPGs. Turns out case was different for JPG and jpg, some of the IDs were six digits instead of five, and some filenames started with "-". I just edited the command and re-ran it a few times.

Comment: Iterative solutions like that are sensible and feasible for a one-off process.  It is like the ultimate in agile programming.  If you're going to have to do the change often, then it is worth devising a script that handles all the deviations and variations in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

If the two parts that you want to keep are always separated by '_download=' then:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)_download=\(.*\)/\2_\1/'
```